# Not copying data after column Z

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a spreadsheet with data from column A:AA.  I'm trying to copy over all of the data from sheet CycleCountResearch in "workbook-a" to CycleCountResearch sheet in "workbook-b".  All of the data except for column AA copy's over.  Column AA contains the filename, so that when it is copied over from workbook a to workbook b, the user can look at the data in workbook b and know which file the data came from.  Is there any recommendation on how to fix column AA not copying over?

Here is the code so far:

```vb
       Sub Export()
    Dim FileName As String
        FileName = "\\InventoryControlDatabase\DoNotOpen\DoNotOpenDCAtest.xlsx"
    'Call function to check if the file is open
        If IsFileOpen(FileName) = False Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Unprotect "123"
        Dim LR As Long
        Dim src As Workbook
        LR = Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set src = Workbooks.Open("\\InventoryControlDatabase\DoNotOpen\DoNotOpenDCAtest.xlsx")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").AutoFilterMode = False
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Range("A4:AA" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="Done", _
              Operator:=xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Range("A5:AA" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        src.Activate
        src.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'src.Worksheets("CycleCountCompleted").UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        Workbooks("DoNotOpenDCA.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
        Call UpdateMasterLog
        Call ClearUpdates
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Range("K2:K2").ClearContents
        'Clears the name of the user editing the sheet
        Else
            MsgBox "Someone else is saving.  Please wait a moment and try again"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: What error does it throw if you comment out the `On Error Resume Next`?  And, why are you not calling `On Error GoTo 0` to reset the error handling later?

Comment: Is the "AA" column visible in the source worksheet?

Comment: Why don't you delete the worksheet in wbB, copy wbA worksheet over and delete column AA? (I'm assuming that you really want to copy over all the data as stated in your question)

Comment: Where in column `AA` is the data (the file name)? You are copying from the 5th row, so if it's above, it won't get copied. Why is the `RemoveDuplicates` line out-commented? Are you sure you want to turn on screen updating before calling the two mysterious procedures? What are they operating on i.e. are they deleting column `AA`? You're not protecting the worksheet when done. Please, add the additional clarifications to your post.

Comment: @Chronocidal ...On Error GoTo 0 Throws a Runtime 1004 error

Comment: @RBarryYoung Column AA is in fact visible in the worksheet.  It is pulling the workbook file name for all active rows.

Comment: @VBasic2008 All data in workbook a starting in row 5 as I've place buttons and row headers above that for the users to see.  Commented out the remove duplicates as there may be duplicate count numbers for column a, which have found to be useful.  I can turn off screen updating, just thought perhaps it would be better to turn on?  Call UpdateMasterLog: Copies same range over into another log sheet.
    Call ClearUpdates: Clears Contents of the cells as the export function is only to be done once all research of data is completed.

Comment: @AccessQ At which line is the error thrown, when you debug it?  Because, that's *probably* where your problem is — or, if it occurred earlier, where it *manifests*.  Stepping through line-by-line with F8 can also let you inspect whether each line has done the right thing or not.

Comment: @Chronocidal Error occurs at: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch").Range("A5:AA" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Comment: @AccessQ And, if you put a breakpoint at that point, are there visible rows/columns?  And, if so, are the visible rows/columns contiguous, or do they have gaps (i.e. "A5:A7,A10:A21,A23", rather than just "A5:A23") — with a filter on, you shouldn't *need* the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to handle the rows, but columns can be trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Backup Data

- This is how I see it. Read through it before running it because you may have to rearrange some lines in the *Finishing Touches* part (e.g. `ClearUpdates`, `UpdateMasterLogs`).
- The best advice from it should be about using variables. They will not slow down the code but will make it more readable, the obvious example being the variables `srg`, `sdrg`, and `sdfrg`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportData()
    
    Const dFilePath As String _
        = "\\InventoryControlDatabase\DoNotOpen\DoNotOpenDCAtest.xlsx"
    
    'Call function to check if the file is open
    If Not IsFileOpen(dFilePath) Then ' source workbook is closed
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        ' Source
        
        Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch")
        sws.Unprotect "123"
        sws.AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Range("B" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Source Range (has headers)
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A4:AA" & slRow)
        srg.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="Done" ' '23' is 'W'
        ' Source Data Range (no headers)
        Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        ' Source Data Filtered Range
        Dim sdfrg As Range
        On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
            Set sdfrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not sdfrg Is Nothing Then
            
            ' Destination
            
            Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
            Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("CycleCountResearch")
            Dim dCell As Range
            Set dCell = dws.Range("A" & dws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            
            sdfrg.Copy¸
            dCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'dwb.Worksheets("CycleCountCompleted").UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates _
                Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
            dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            
            ' Finishing Touches
        
            UpdateMasterLog
            ClearUpdates
            'Clear the name of the user editing the sheet
            sws.Range("K2:K2").ClearContents
            
            sws.AutoFilterMode = False
            sws.Protect "123"
            
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True '
            
            MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
            
        Else ' no filtered data
               
            sws.AutoFilterMode = False
            MsgBox "No filtered data.", vbCritical
            'Exit Sub
               
        End If
            
    Else ' source workbook is open
        
        MsgBox "Someone else is saving. Please, try again later.", vbExclamation
        'Exit Sub
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  The addition of clear variables seems to resolve the issue.